# Multi step form with clickable steps

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello can some one help me how can I achieve designing multi step for as shown in image [image]

I referred link but in that there is a next button to move to a new step but i want numbers also clickable. How do i achieve that?

Comment: I refered http://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz link

Comment: Is will support twitter-bootstrap. @Chandrika Desai

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bootstrap wizard like [twitter bootstrap wizard](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-progressbar.html)

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
    var $current = index+1;
    var $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
    $('#rootwizard').find('.bar').css({width:$percent+'%'});
  }});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>

<div id="rootwizard">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Forth</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Fifth</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Sixth</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab7" data-toggle="tab">Seventh</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab7">
      7
    </div>
    <ul class="pager wizard">
      <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="#">First</a></li>
      <li class="previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Last</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But i want something similar in wireframe

Comment: What do you mean by `wireframe`?